Fixed effect model in Python
Hi all I am now learning how to do a fixed-effect model in Python. This post is really helpful but I am still a bit confused at the part of "demeaning"

Fixed effect in Pandas or Statsmodels

In @Karl D.'s answer, the code for option 3 he kindly provided (is attached below), I am not sure why it is nesscessary to add back the ybar and xbar after demeaning. This seems like re-introduce the fixed effect that we wanted to remove? And thanks to Karl.D, his answer is really helpful. My reputation is not enough to directly comment under his answer so I decided to post the question.
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import patsy

def areg(formula,data=None,absorb=None,cluster=None): 

    y,X = patsy.dmatrices(formula,data,return_type='dataframe')

    ybar = y.mean()
    y = y -  y.groupby(data[absorb]).transform('mean') + ybar

    Xbar = X.mean()
    X = X - X.groupby(data[absorb]).transform('mean') + Xbar

    reg = sm.OLS(y,X)
    # Account for df loss from FE transform
    reg.df_resid -= (data[absorb].nunique() - 1)

    return reg.fit(cov_type='cluster',cov_kwds={'groups':data[cluster].values})

Thank you
What if we simply do:
y = y -  y.groupby(data[absorb]).transform('mean')
X = X - X.groupby(data[absorb]).transform('mean')

reg = sm.OLS(y,X)

Is it a correct fixed-effect model?

a note on the statistics/econometrics of it. Separate group demeaning if there are several categories is only correct if the panels or clusters are balanced, that is, all cell counts are the same.

Not being the original author, I can only speculate about the reasons. Most likely, it’s done to reintroduce the intercept. While this might make little or no sense when the observed entities have significant differences in their values, it can be useful when the observations are more comparable, as it effectively brings the intercept back into the model. It's important to note that xbar and ybar are constant values, so they don’t reintroduce the fixed effects themselves.
